# Pipwin install/PyInstaller with python which is not in path

Tags: python

I'm trying to install PyAudio to a version of python 3.7 which is not in path, I've been able to install Pipwin into this version but I can't Install PyAudio, maybe I'm running the pipwin from the path Python, when I try and install it, it says that the program is already installed in the path location, how can I change this to install to the other version of Python?

I've had a go at doing this

```
>pipwin install PyAudio --file=C:\Users\salman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37.exe
```

But no luck, can someone help?

Edit:
Also, I then need to compile this into an exe, I'm using pyinstaller to do this, but again, I need it to compile using this 3.7 version, not the newer 3.8 version because of it not working, how would I do that?

Thank you

Comment: `C:\Users\salman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37.exe -m pip install PyAudio`

Comment: Actually I just realised that I gave the wrong location, it's C:\Users\salman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37/python.exe

Comment: The new error though is Command "C:\Users\salman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\salman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-sei53rb9\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\salman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6k71gfas\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\salman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sei53rb9\PyAudio\